# Open iTunes from AIR Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, itunes

I am trying to launch iTunes application from AIR desktop application of Flex. But I am unable to do the same as the code is doing in the catch error of try catch loop.

Below is the snippet I am using for opening iTunes from AIR:

```
try
                    {
                        if(currentOS.indexOf("Windows") >= 0)
                        {
                            prepareFilesForSynciOS('Windows');
                            fileItunes = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\iTunes\\iTunes.exe");
                            //fileItunes1 = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("C:\Program Files (x86)\iTunes\iTunes.exe");

                            //Alert.show(" fileItunes " + fileItunes.nativePath);
                            //Alert.show(" fileItunes1 " + fileItunes1.nativePath);

                            if(!fileItunes.exists)
                            {
                                fileItunes = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("C:\\Program Files\\iTunes\\iTunes.exe");
                                //fileItunes1 = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("C:\Program Files (x86)\iTunes\iTunes.exe");

                                //Alert.show(" fileItunes 64 " + fileItunes.nativePath);
                                //Alert.show(" fileItunes1 64 " + fileItunes1.nativePath);
                            }


                            fileItunes.openWithDefaultApplication();
                        }
                        else if(currentOS.indexOf("Mac") >= 0 )
                        {
                            prepareFilesForSynciOS('Mac');
                            fileItunes = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("/Applications/iTunes.app");
                            fileItunes.openWithDefaultApplication();
                        }
                    }
                    catch(e:Error)
                    {
                        //Alert.show("iTunes was not found on this Computer.");
                        navigateToURL( new URLRequest("http://www.apple.com/itunes/download/"));
                    }
```

I got TypeError 1009 when I made alert to the error message.

Any help is appreciated. :)

Thanks,
Ankit.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What isn't working? Are you saying your exception handler is being triggered? What line was your NRE on? There isn't anything in your catch block to trigger an NRE as Alert is static.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing anything outside of the Air security sandbox is a violation. You cannot run the ITunes application unless it is in the sandboxed location as that of the ITunes.

Because Air cannot do this, you may have to rely on the native extension ie., c++ or any other native application programming(I guess they are already available outside somewhere) to invoke the itunes application. Use sockets of Air to invoke the same on the native application.